# How to display only 3 post per page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hello i am new to wordpress

i want to display only 3 post per page in blog .

Could anyone help me how to display only 3 posts per page in wordpress blog ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add pagination to a wordpress site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380883/how-to-add-pagination-to-a-wordpress-site)

Answer (score 0):

In the admin panel of your Wordpress installation, just go to Settings -> Reading and where it says 'Blog pages show at most' reduce this to 3 items.

Answer (score 0):

If you know coding you can do this by adding the following code into your page.

Add following 2 line code just before your loop starts

```
global $query_string;
query_posts("{$query_string}&posts_per_page=3");

while (have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

From your admin panel go to Settings > Reading and make 'Blog pages show at most' 3 items.